# Fixing water leak without turning off water. (Water pipe busted, can't get company to turn off water) Please Help

Tags: plumbing, leak

Trying to fix a water line that froze then busted, I can't get the water company to cut off the water, the valve at the meter no longer shuts off water to the home (I was not informed that the new policy states that the homeowner must provide own shutoff). Water company said they would send someone at 1pm yesterday, almost 24 hrs later, water still flowing heavily. My question is, is it possible to glue this cpvc line while water is flowing? My thought process is to just cut the line before the break and install a shutoff valve until a plumber can get out to fix it (Which will be days from what I've been told by the landlord). I am open to any suggestions. Please Help.

Comment: Are you the homeowner or a renter?  If a renter keep pictures and have all communications recorded and kept.  It is landlords responsibility to fix and repairs.  If a homeowner then there pipe freeze kits to freeze water to work on pipes.  If leak is bad then cutting the pipe to install valve probably won't get stuff wetter.

Comment: *Might* have a better chance with a Sharkbite. If the break is a full-flow break then you've got nothing to lose. If the break is much less than that (perhaps a couple gallons a minute) then you risk going from "bad" to "worse".

Comment: It might be helpful to provide information and/or photos of where the leak is, the volume of water coming out, photos of your access to the leak, etc.  Also, I've never seen a water meter that doesn't have valves before and after to isolate the meter for change-outs, etc. Are you sure there's no cut-off valves? These would be located at the actual water meter not a remote readout device.

Comment: My father is the renter, we contacted the landlord and the water company as soon as the pipe broke approximately 1pm yesterday. The break is about 1 foot long, and I'm certain it's full flow, because of the length is why I thought of just putting a temporary shutoff valve but I can't find a cpvc glue that works when wet. In this case, it would be very wet.

Comment: @gnicko I will try to get pics in a bit, the shutoff at the road/meter use to stop flow, I've used it before when replacing water heater elements and it's where the company told me to stop the water before, but they have since had a "Policy Change" and now the homeowner is responsible for providing a shutoff and the valve does nothing when turned. Thanks Aqua.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got nothing to lose by trying a Sharkbite. Something like [this one from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/SharkBite-3-4-in-Push-to-Connect-PVC-IPS-x-3-4-in-CTS-Brass-Ball-Valve-25550LF/302360738):

[image: Sharkbite PVC brass valve]

It won't be easy, but it is better than continuing with a flood. Make sure you get the right size - if you're not sure, get every size that looks close and return whatever you don't use (Home Depot and similar stores are very good about that - I've had employees tell me to do that.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few products that come to mind...

[Resin-permeated fiberglass tape.](https://www.plumbingsupply.com/repairkit.html) This stuff is a fiberglass tape enpregmented with a water-activated resin adhesive. Basically, you wrap the pipe with this stuff and the water causes the resin to fuse into a "permanent," fiberglass reinforced patch. I'd use this for a temporary fix and then replace the broken length of pipe later.

[A mechanical pipe patch fitting.](https://www.plumbingsupply.com/pipe-repair.html) This goes around the pipe and clamps down to seal the leak with a rubber gasket. This might be too short for your situation, but they do make various sizes. Again, this will be a good temporary fix until you can fix it permanently.

[A combination of Sharkbite fittings and a length of replacement pipe.](https://www.plumbingsupply.com/sharkbite-fittings.html) Cut out the broken length of pipe and replace it using the push-fit Sharkbite fittings. The straight couplings are probably what you'll need, but while you're at it, depending on the location of the burst pipe, this might be a good opportunity to install a cut-off valve. This is going to get you plenty wet and could require some "gymnastics" to get things together, but you already have water flowing freely, so that might not be as bad as it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

I would give a Push fit valve a try similar to the ones shown below. You would install it with the valve open and then close it afterwards to stop the water.

[image]

There are also emergency repair sleeves from Home depot that could also work it the slit is not too big. See picture below.

[image]